# Render and redirect_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render

I just answered a question on a quiz and the question is as follows:

Which of the following is an invalid statement regarding render and redirect_to?

- `render` doesn't send a new request but `redirect_to` does
- `redirect_to` doesn't send a new request but `render` does
- `render` will not cause the current action to stop executing
- `redirect_to` will not cause the current action to stop executing

I selected the Option 1 as my answer but it came out to be wrong. I checked online and found this [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActionView/Rendering_and_Redirecting) where it's clearly stated that `redirect_to` sends a new request to browser:

> > There is an important difference between render and redirect_to: render will tell Rails what view it should use (with the same parameters you may have already sent) but redirect_to sends a new request to the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option two will be the right answer as in question clearly written: Which of the following is an **invalid statement**

As you understood and know `redirect_to` send a new request but in option it says that doesn't send so it becomes **invalid statement** and your answer should be

```
redirect_to doesn't send a new request but render does
```

**Note:**

**`Kindly read question properly and understand it first before give the answer..`**

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that the question was asking for the **invalid statement** o_O ,I feel stupid now :/

Comment: Can someone explain why the forth option is not correct?

Comment: @RSB: I did not downvoted your answer. But for your info kindly [read this](https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1210155#redirect_to-is-not-return) hope it makes you clear

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed the `invalid` word in the question, the **correct answer would be Option 4**

```
redirect_to will not cause the current action to stop executing
```

Option 1 `render doesn't send a new request but redirect_to does` is valid, since `redirect_to` sends a get request to an action of type `get`, but `render` just renders the `view`, it has nothing to do with the other `action`

Comment: `redirect_to` does not cause the action to stop executing. It is not like calling `return` in a Ruby method